# PHP Creating two dimensional arrays dependent on a function

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this:

```
[apple] => 11
[pear] => 5
[banana] => 3
[cucumber] => 2
[tomatoes] => 8
```

I would like to create multi-dimensional array like this:

```
[randomArrayName1]
        [apple] => 11
        [banana] => 3
        [tomatoes] => 8
[randomArrayName2]
        [pears] => 5
        [cucumber] => 2
```

I wrote this below but it is not working and I have no clue how to make it do: what I need it to do

```
$quantity = array();
foreach($fruit as $key => $value) {
    $quantity = Finder($key);
}
```

`randomArrayName1` and `randomArrayName2` will be generated depending on `Finder()` function's result. Depending on that result I want fruit array to be created as a second dimension  array.

---

Solution:
The problem was that the function I wrote that created names like randomArrayName1, randomArrayName2... was in fact a XML function. Therefore, result of this function was not an array, it was XML simple object. This caused problem on creating multidimensional array. Once I implemented the code below it converted SimpleXML to Array and code worked fine.
$type is SimpleXML array
$out is result array

```
   foreach ( (array) $type as $index => $node )
    $out[$index] = ( is_object ( $node ) ) ? xml2array ( $node ) : $node;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `array_reduce`. It takes three arguments, an initial array to operate on, a function which should operate on each element (which in turn requires two arguments, `$carry`, which is a variable that gets passed through to the function each time through the return statement, and `$item`, which is the array item being operated on) and finally an "initial" value for `$carry` within the function, which in this case is going to be our multidimensional array that gets eventually returned.

This is an example where the `Finder` function returns a key based on whether the value of the items in the array is odd or even, and sorts the values accordingly.

Note that we are operating on the `array_keys` of fruits, so that we have access to both key and value inside our reducer.

```
<?php

$fruit = ['apple' => 11, 'pear' => 5, 'banana' => 3, 'cucumber' => 2, 'tomatoes' => 8];

function Finder($fruit) {
    return $fruit % 2 == 0 ? 'even' : 'odd';
}

$multi = array_reduce(array_keys($fruit), function($carry, $item) use ($fruit) {
    $val = $fruit[$item];
    $carry[Finder($val)][$item] = $val;
    return $carry;
}, []);

var_dump($multi);

/* // output
array(2) {
  ["odd"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["apple"]=>
    int(11)
    ["pear"]=>
    int(5)
    ["banana"]=>
    int(3)
  }
  ["even"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["cucumber"]=>
    int(2)
    ["tomatoes"]=>
    int(8)
  }
}
*/
```

Comment: Great code this is the idea I am using to code it but I get this error PHP Warning: file_get_contents(.blabla.com/xml/word1 word2 word3 word4. And it is because Finder($key) is getting multiple values all at once. I need to ensure it gets only once at a time and structures the array accordingly. P.S. Sorry yes I did reply wrong place.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create the new index or access it if it has already been created and then create another element under that with the existing key and assign the value:

```
$quantity = array();
foreach($fruit as $key => $value) {
    $quantity[Finder($key)][$key] = $value;
}
```

This is assuming that `Finder()` is returning a string like `randomArrayName1`.

Comment: I am getting this error -> [xx] PHP Warning:  Illegal offset type in /home/xx/public_html/xx.php on line 19

Comment: Well I added `$quantity = array();` back in, apparently you've already defined it as a string somewhere.

Comment: `var_dump(Finder($key));` to see what is returned.

Comment: So Finder($key) needs to have 1 word at a time to structure the whole array. Instead when I run the code Finder($key) is getting all the words at once, not one by one. Here is the error code. PHP Warning:  file_get_contents(http://www..blabla.com/xml/word1 word2 word3 word4.. I coded Finder($key) to accept 1 word at a time, run some xml code and return a result. That result will be first part of array in the case above for example I am assuming it will return randomArrayName1 for some ant randomArrayName2 for others.

Comment: The problem is why inside the foreach Finder($key) is getting multiple values at once?